# How to match everything (including new line) up to the first occurance of a substring?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

As the title states, how to match anything up to the first occurance of the substring `<!--`?

Here's my test:

```
$string = "-->Hello world\r\nI feel <!--good <!--again";
preg_match("/-->.*<!--/s", $string, $extract);
var_dump($extract);
```

The result is:

```
array (size=1)
 0 => string '-->Hello world
I feel <!--good <!--' (length=36)
```

Where I need it to stop after the first time it sees `<!--`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to make the [quantifier lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), telling it to match as few characters as possible (instead of as many as possible, as unadorned quantifiers do because they are greedy by default):

```
preg_match("/-->.*?<!--/s", $string, $extract);
```

Comment: Even though, this is a simple example of an a lot bigger regex, this actually does exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To complete Tim Pietzcker answer, there is an other way without the s modifier:

```
preg_match("/\C*?<!--/", $string, $extract);
```

Comment: Hm, RegexBuddy says that PHP doesn't support `\C`, and I couldn't find it [in the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php) (or I've been looking in the wrong place) - can you point me to the docs?

Comment: @TimPietzcker: of course : http://pcre.org/pcre.txt (never believe a regex tester)

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll ask Jan Goyvaerts if he wants to update RegexBuddy. However, as the docs you linked to say: "In general, the `\C` escape sequence is best avoided." and "The  feature  is provided in Perl in order to match individual bytes in UTF-8 mode, but it is unclear how it can usefully  be  used.  Because  `\C` breaks up characters into individual data units, matching one unit with `\C` in a UTF mode means that the  rest  of the string may start with a malformed UTF character." - sounds like a good idea not to go down that rabbit hole...

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Indeed, however, I have made any test and I never succeed to break an UTF8 string. If you find a good example, don't hesitate to post it.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: I have found an example: `preg_match("/H\C\C\C/", "Hጷello world", $match);` If you remove one `\C` the pattern fails. But using `\C` with an undefined length quantifier and followed by an explicit subpattern seem to avoid any problems.